# How to make tool tip or popupwindow if i click or mouse over on text

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Asp Application, I've to make one tool-tip or popup window if i mouse-over or click specific text respectively . message(tool-tip or popup window) is get from database table . Please help me to make it .

[image]

you can see the red circle in above image. if i mouse-over to that '4', have to see tooltip or popupwindow value get from table.

Comment: The HTML `title` attribute is generally used as a tooltip by browsers. Is that not the case here?

Comment: i dint get u .please can you explain

Comment: The HTML `title` attribute (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3) can be used to assign a value to an HTML element which browsers generally use for a tooltip.  (I think it's pretty universal, but I don't know _every_ browser.)  So if you have an HTML element for which you want a tooltip, and that tooltip is just text, simply give that element a `title` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In OnRowDataBound Event, you can make the paricular column as link... 

 e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "<a href= '#' style='cursor:pointer' onclick ='Popupwindow() class = 'linknormal'></a>";
```

Above code used to call javascript function with name of popupwindow...when use click that particular column ...the javascript function will bw fired..

Javascript code:

```
   function popupwindow()
    {
    window.open(URL,name,specs,replace);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use client side code plus JQuery ToolTip plugin. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip